# How big would a giant pig need to be in order to carry a 10-foot tall humanoid on its back?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, warfare, transportation, mounts

A book that I'm currently writing called Surge features [an enemy faction called the Degenerates that are heavily inspired](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FantasyCounterpartCulture) [by the Scythians](http://arkhamhaus.com/scythian-scouts.html) (Indo-Iranian horse nomads that ruled the Eurasian Steppes and Central Asia from the 10th century BCE to the 3rd century CE) and consists mostly of humans parasitized by a prehistoric endoparasite called Echidna (named after the Dracaena that gave birth to numerous monsters in Greek mythology), which parasitizes and radically alters the entire physiology of a wide variety of organisms from the phylum Chordata.

Parasitized humans are transformed into nocturnal humanoids that are facultative quadrupedals and divided into three distinct subspecies, [named after the sons of Hercules and Echidna](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReligiousAndMythologicalThemeNaming) (all of which were ancestors of the Scythians):

- Agathyrsus (*Falhumanus clavapugnus*): Physically imposing and immensely strong Degenerates used mostly as shock troops, *cataphractii* and heavy infantry
- Gelonus (*Falhumanus tetrabrachius*): Lightly-built and four-armed Degenerates which act as scouts, light infantry and cavalry whose purpose is to advance beyond their own front lines for the intent of harassing enemies from afar
- Scythes (*Falhumanus sagittarius*): Four-eyed Degenerates that have excellent vision and are deployed as marksmen and mounted riflemen, who engage their targets at long range.

Because they are fighting a losing war against a shadowy multi-national black ops unit called *S.W.O.R.D* using cutting-edge military technology, the Degenerates are forced to engage in guerrilla and asymmetrical warfare against *S.W.O.R.D*. One such tactic involves Gelonians and Scythi (acting as mounted riflemen/grenadiers and light/normal cavalry) working together in anti-armour hunter-killer cells commanded by Agathyrsi *cataphractii* (heavily armored cavalry) for the purpose of ambushing armoured vehicles like armoured personnel carriers, tanks and scout cars, utilizing melee weaponry and firearms outfitted with special attachments and high-calibre armour-piercing ammunition coated in *scythicon*.

[In lieu of horses, the Degenerates use a variety of parasitised animals as mounts](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeastOfBattle) and the mounts mostly used by Agathyrsi *cataphractii* are [mutated feral pigs designated](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FullBoarAction) [Phaea](http://www.theoi.com/Ther/HusKrommyon.html) and Agathyrsi ride these things using horned saddles similar to those used by the Sarmatians (Indo-Iranian horse nomads closely related to the Scythians) and leather loops as stirrups.

This leaves me with two problems:

- How big would Phaea need to
  be in order to carry a fully armoured Agathyrsi *cataphract*
  ([wearing plate
  armour](https://periklisdeligiannis.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/cataphract2.jpg)
  or an [ankle-length cuirass with parapleuridia made of interlaced narrow plates](http://warfare.netau.net/WRG/AotMaPW-86-Saka_Cavalryman.jpg)) sporting heavy weaponry, since Agathyrsi stand around 10 feet tall (3.0 meters) and weigh 272 kilograms (599.66 pounds)?
- What sort of body structure would Phaea need to support the weight of a fully armoured Agathyrsi *cataphract*?

Comment: This pig outweighs its rider 5 to 1: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2581136/Riding-hog-Farmer-rides-pig-market-illness-left-sick-walk.html. This is a little below the ratio for a light horse, so 6 to 1 seems a good number. However, in the video in Youtube, the pig moves the legs by pairs, which makes an unstable movement. Maybe a good saddle like https://www.rootsimple.com/2013/10/picture-sunday-riding-the-pig-again/ would help?

Comment: This is a good question, but most of its text is irrelevant. You can remove everything that does not have to do with pig riding (i.e.: race names, the fact that they are parasites...) and then more people will be willing to read through all of it. As it is, it may cause a TL;DR feeling.

Comment: How heavy were the war horses of the medieval period which had to carry knights and armor? Scale up from there.

Comment: What is the gravity?  Because of the square-cube law, we won't be able to simply double the size of a pig without it weighing 8 times more; in which case it's bones need to be stronger and heavier, etc.  Big things move like hippos and elephants.  only small things move like cats and lizards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb pack animals can carry about 30% of their body weight reliably. This is for purposes of packing however, a battle charger would need speed, and so one would need to have that ratio be even better, maybe 15% to 20% of the animals body weight. Minimum size to be reliably ridden is about 800 kilograms, but for battle purposes I would say the lower size limit would need to be roughly about 1000 kilograms or larger. This is an animal that is going to be bigger than a bull moose.